# Div element to float over flash in GWT

Tags: flash, gwt, html, transparent

In my GWT app, i've integrated a flash object. And there is a GWT calender component left to it. When I open the calender, it goes under the flash. But I want it to appear above the flash.

I added  in the  and wmode="transparent" in the embed tag, and this was done in the chrome development console. But it didn't work.

So am I doing the right thing or can I do what i need with the GWT calender?

thanks....

Comment: Not an idea about GWT, but it seems the issue of `z-index` CSS attribute. set lower z-index value of flash object then GWT Calandar's object.

Comment: You may also want to change your wmode to "opaque" unless there's a really good reason other than what you mentioned for it to be transparent. It'll be more performant that way.

Comment: Are you using RootLayoutPanel as the base container?

Comment: I tried z-index, but it didnt work.

Container is not the root panel, in fact a Flow panel